# How do I refer back to the jQuery matched element's value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following code:

```
$(".force-selection").blur(function() {
        var value = $('matched-item').val();
        //check if the input's value matches the selected item
        if(value != $('#matched-item').data('selected-item')) {
            //they don't, the user must have typed something else
            $('#matched-item')
                .val('') //clear the input's text
                .data('selected-item', ''); //clear the selected item
        }
});
```

How do I refer to the element that was matched by the $(".force-selection") jQuery selector? I am not very clear on anonymous JS functions, and I'm confused as to how people know to sometimes declare them like this:

```
function()
```

and sometimes like this:

```
function(event)
```

and sometimes like this:

```
function(element, update, options)
```

and all the other ways.

Comment: Store `this` in a variable. PS. You're missing a sharp (`#`) in the selector at line `var value =..`.

Comment: The differences between those functions are just what parameters they take.

Comment: Why not cache the selector? DONE

Comment: Because I don't know what it means to cache a selector. That's why I am asking such a simple question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.currentTarget` passed with the jQuery event object as first argument:

```
$(".force-selection").blur(function(e) { //<-- define e as parameter for this function. it's short for "event"
        e.currentTarget; //The element a blur was triggered on
        var value = $('#matched-item').val(); //<-- add "#"



        //check if the input's value matches the selected item
        if(value != $('#matched-item').data('selected-item')) {
            //they don't, the user must have typed something else
            $('#matched-item')
                .val('') //clear the input's text
                .data('selected-item', ''); //clear the selected item
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the this keyword, it refers to the current closure. Wrap it in a jQuery call and it turns into the referenced element.

```
$(".force-selection").blur(function() {
    var value = $('matched-item').val();
    //check if the input's value matches the selected item
    if(value != $('#matched-item').data('selected-item')) {
        //they don't, the user must have typed something else
        $('#matched-item')
            .val('') //clear the input's text
            .data('selected-item', ''); //clear the selected item
    }
    //-----
    $(this) == current .force-selection
    //-----
});
```